# Repeating strings but not ints when reading from files

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I've written a function that uses `fscanf("%s &d &d &d")` to read from a file. For some reason, when I display the output, all the integer values are correct, but the strings are all the same. `food_stuff` is a `struct` held in an array.

*EDIT
I've tried using a `for` to add each element from one array to the other, and I've tried `strcpy`.

Here's the function.

```
int readFromFile()
{
    char*name;
    int type;
    int cals;
    int price;

    FILE * food_file;
    food_file = fopen ("food_file.txt", "r");
    while(fscanf(food_file, "%s %d %d %d", name, &type, &cals, &price)!=EOF)
    {
        food_stuff fs;
        fs.name = name;
        fs.type = type;
        fs.calories = cals;
        fs.price = price;
        fflush(stdin);
        addItem(fs);
    }

}
```

Comment: Two things: (i) you need to allocate memory for the `name` field and (ii) never call `fflush` on `stdin`.

Comment: @PaulR I allocated memory with `name = (char*) malloc (20+1);` and got rid of the `fflush(stdin);` but nothing changed. What does flushing the standard input do exactly?

Comment: Problem may be in your `additem` function. To be sure, print the values before calling `additem`.

Comment: @Dipto Unfortunately, all the values return as normal. I already have it working with a populating function, so there is no problem with the addItem function, or displayAll function, nor the struct itself.

Comment: Note also that in `addItem` you will need to use `strcpy` to copy the `name` field, i.e. don't just copy the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter already has pointed out, you need to allocate memory for your variable `name`. Because the variable is temporary, you could just declare a local char array on the stack instead of allocationg memory on the heap:

```
char name[40];
```

Your problem is that the `name` field in your structure is probably also only a pointer to char. That pointer points to `name` for all footstuff structs you generate, which is the same for all instances, only with different contents. (What's worse: That buffer won't exist any more if you leave `readFromFile`, invalidating the `name` field for every foodstuff.)

One possible solution is to make the `name` field also a buffer, e.g:

```
typedef struct food_stuff food_stuff;

struct food_stuff {
    char name[40];
    int type;
    int cals;
    int price;
};
```

When you assign the read data to the struct, don't copy the pointer, but copy the contents with `strcpy`. (You need to include `<string.h>` for that):

```
strcpy(fs.name, name);
```

This solution assumes that all names are less than 39 characters long, which is not a safe assumption for real data. You should specify a width on the `%s` format in your call to  `fscanf`.

Another solution is leave the struct definition as I assume it is now with `char *name` and to allocate memory for each new struct. You still have to copy the contents, though:

```
fs.name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
// error check omitted
strcpy(fs.name, name);
```

This solution requires that you free the extra memory allocated when you free the foodstuff structs.

Comment: @M Oehm Thank you for your most excellent and comprehensive answer. (WORKED)